# Dot in division (1./2)

Tags: c++

This code solves the program : Create an algorithm in the form of a flowchart, write and debug the task using recursive and ordinary functions. Corresponding results.

What is dot used for here "x = (1. / 2) * (f + (a / f));" ?

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int k, e, x, a, d, n, f, s;
d = 1;
do {
    e = 1;
    do {
        cout << "Press 1 to use recurrent solution method, press 2 to use nun recurrent solution 
method" << endl;
        cin >> k;
        if (k == 1 || k == 2) e = 2;

    } while (e == 1);

    switch (k)
    {
    case 1:
    {
        cout << "Enter the numder a:" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        cout << "Enter the numder n:" << endl;
        cin >> n;
        x = (1. / 2)*(1 + a);
        f = x;
        s = f;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            x = (1. / 2) * (f + (a / f));
            s += x;
            f = x;
        }
        cout << "Result: " << s << endl;
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
        cout << " Enter the numder a:" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        x = sqrt(a);
        cout << "Result: " << x << endl;
    }
    break;
    }
    cout << "Press 1 to repeat!" << endl;
    cin >> d;
    } while (d == 1);
    }
```

Comment: The dot just means the value is a floating-point value instead of an integer. It's the same as using 1.0.

Comment: Without it, `1/2` would be integer division and result in zero.

Comment: did you write the code? If not please mark it as such by adding a reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot in "x = (1. / 2) * (f + (a / f));" is used for assuring that the division is interpreted as a float division instead of an integer division, so the result of (1/2) is 0.5 instead of 0.